# NAudio - Streaming byte[] of wav makes it play slow

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I am trying to read bytes from a wav file and send it across to a stream but it plays slowly.
Could you please help me to know the right way of populating the byte[]?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you using NAudio to both read the WAV file and play the data?
you need to make sure you use the same WaveFormat at both ends

Comment: Hi Mark,

Thanks for your response. I was trying to get in touch with you. I am happy :)

Well, I am trying to intercept mic datarecieved buffer byte[] and pass a new wav file as byte[]. When passing the new sound data as byte[] I am using File.ReadAllBytes.

Could you please suggest a good way of sending the byte[] in the right way?

Comment: Hi Mark,

                    WaveStream outStream = new WaveFileReader("test.wav");
                    outStream = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(outStream);
                    outStream = new BlockAlignReductionStream(outStream); // reduces choppiness
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[outStream.Length];
                    outStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)outStream.Length - 1);
                    Array.Copy(buffer, 0, newSoundByteArray, startIndex, buffer.Length);
newSoundByteArray is sent to stream and is playing slow. Waveformat matches.

Comment: how do you go about playing the data?

Comment: In the MicInterceptor class of SkypeFX I assign this newSoundByteArray to args.Buffer  
 and use:

 bufferStream.SetLatestInBuffer(args.Buffer);
                    //process it out through the effects
                    OutputStream.Read(args.Buffer, 0, args.Buffer.Length);
                    
                    // Playing it back
                        outStream.Write(args.Buffer, 0, args.Buffer.Length);
                 

Thanks.

Comment: ok, I didn't realise you were using SkypeFx. Skype plays it itself. You have to provide 16 bit 44.1kHz mono. Convert the audio to that format before passing it back to Skype.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you please tell me if I've to do anything else other than the two snippets I just showed? The test.wav is of the same format 16 bit 44.1kHz mono. Please help.

Comment: Hi Mark,

I see that both the wave formats match. Mic's format is 16 bit, 44100 sample rate and mono

 public SkypeBufferStream(int sampleRate)
        {
            waveFormat = new WaveFormat(sampleRate, 16, 1);
        }

and test.wav's wave format is also the same. Could you please tell me what I am missing? Thanks

Comment: Hi Mark,

It would be great if you could help me with your suggestion.

Thanks for your help.